# Only root element is getting inserted in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write the method for inserting the element in the BST using following method:

```
//method to insert the data in bst

public static void insertBST(Node temp, int data){

if(temp== null){
    root1= new Node(data);
    return;
}
Queue<Node> q= new LinkedList<Node>();
q.add(temp);
while(!q.isEmpty()){
    
    temp= q.peek();
    q.remove();
    if(temp== null){
        temp= new Node(data);
        break;
    }
    if(temp.data< data){
        q.add(temp.right);
    }
    else if(temp.data>data)
        q.add(temp.left);
}
}
```

But when I trying to print the elements of the BST in Inorder, only the root element is getting printed

```
//Method for inorder traversal

public static void inorder(Node root){
if(root == null)
    return;
inorder(root.left);
System.out.print(root.data+ " ");
inorder(root.right);
}

//Structure of Node class
    public static class Node{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
    public Node(int data){
        this.data= data;
        left= null;
        right= null;
    }
}
static Node root1= null;
```

main method call:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    insertBST(root1,5);
    insertBST(root1,3);
    insertBST(root1,7);
    insertBST(root1,4);
    inorder(root1);
    }
```

Please tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: I don't see where your code adds anything to the given node or the root node. You are just adding stuff to a queue and not to the nodes.

Comment: i dont think so, because i am fetching the top element from the queue and then if its null then i am adding it to the tree. Could you please elaborate more or it would be a great help if you could update my code.

Comment: No. Reread your code. If it's null you create a new node but you don't add it anywhere. There is no place where you assign anything that is not null to any existing node's left or right.

Comment: hmm.. correct. So how do I do that? I though since I am traversing and its a linked list so the temp node will have link to the previous node.